# XPath getting <li> inside <random> tag

Tags: java, xpath, netbeans

[snapshot of aiml file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9WAPn.png) ||
[code snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GXcmG.png)

I am trying to parse this .aiml file using DOM Parser + XPath but am not able / unsure how to get the li text inside the random tag, code snippet is what i have so far, any help appreciated. I am still very very new to this.

**.aiml File**

```
<category>
<pattern>100 *</pattern><that>HOW MUCH *</that>
<template>Wow that is <random>
<li>expensive.</li>
<li>a lot of money.</li>
<li>more than I have.</li>
</random>
</template></category>
```

**Code**

```
String expression = "/aiml/category";

NodeList nodeList = (NodeList) xPath.compile(expression).evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);


for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
Node nNode = nodeList.item(i);
System.out.println("\nCurrent Element :" + nNode.getNodeName()); //this returns <category>

            if ((nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE)) {
                Element eElement = (Element) nNode;
String question = eElement.getElementsByTagName("pattern").item(0).getTextContent();
String answer = eElement.getElementsByTagName("template").item(0).getTextContent();

                System.out.println("Question : " + question);
                System.out.println("Answer : " + answer);
   }
}
```

Comment: Please add the code directly into the question rather than capturing code in an image

Comment: @DatNguyen updated!!

Comment: Please add the content of the aiml file to the question as well

Comment: @DatNguyen so sorry haha

Comment: Hi, Did this answer below work for you?

Answer (score 0):

To get `li` elements text contents, you could use the below code :

```
InputSource inputSource = new InputSource( new FileInputStream( new File("category.aiml") ) ) ;
  Object li = xpath.evaluate("//category/template/random/li", inputSource, XPathConstants.NODESET);
 List<String> liElements = new ArrayList<>();
  if ( li != null )
  {

        NodeList liNodes = (NodeList)li;
        for ( int i = 0; i < liNodes.getLength(); i++ )
        {
            liElements.add( liNodes.item(i).getTextContent() );
        }
   }
```

It works using [`javax.xml.xpath`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/xpath/package-summary.html)'s [`evaluate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/xpath/XPath.html#evaluate(java.lang.String,%20org.xml.sax.InputSource,%20javax.xml.namespace.QName))
The xpath in the code  `//category/template/random/li` gets the nodes on that path as a `NODESET`.
Iterate over the nodes and call `getTextContent()` to get text of each `li`.